# Power series representation of $\frac{1}{1-e^z}$ to classify singularity.

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series, residue-calculus, singularity

I want to classify the singularity of $\frac{1}{1-e^z}$ at $0$.

With a "direct" power series expansion, I got 
$$\frac{1}{-\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{z^k}{k!}}$$

This looks like an essential singularity, but it is not in the standard form for a power series, and the series is in the denominator, so I can't just pull the reciprocal in.

Is there a way to transform this expression into a power series? Or is there a better way to show the singularity is essential?

Comment: To invert, write $g(z)=a_0+a_1z+a_2z^2+\dots$.  Then $1=-(\sum_{k\ge1}z^{k-1}/k!)(g(z))$.  So you can solve for the coefficients.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f(z)=1/(1-e^z)$.  There's a simple pole at $0$, because $zf(z)=-1$ at $z=0$, and $zf(z)$ is holomorphic and nonzero in a nbhd of $0$.  Indeed, $zf(z)=1/-(1+z/2+z^2/6+\dots)=-1-z/2-5/12z^2+\dots$.